# Rotate a PDF without changing orientation

Tags: pdf, rotation, orientation

while the topic of my question seems to be a well supported feature of many PDF manipulation packages and tools out there, I need to make clear that I don't want to rotate the PDF.

I have a PDF that exposes a portrait orientation (A4) with dimensions WxH 297x210 (A4 rotated).

Now, what I need to achieve, is that this PDF has landscape orientation while preserving the dimensions.

I am not sure what this requires me to do.

If I use Adobe Illustrator to change document format to the desired position, I also need to rotate the contents. If I put this page into the badly designed PDF, the formfields and all annotations on this page are still in the portrait orientation.

How can I rotate them to match the new page orientation? There seems to be no tool support for this kind of task.

Thanks for your support!

Thomas

Comment: I really don't understand what you want :) anyone else?

Comment: @maf-soft Inside a PDF the dimensions of a page are given by a rectangle and a rotation angle. If you want to have A4 landscape you can either use a 297x210 rectangle and no (or a 180°) rotation or a 210x297 rectangle and a 90° or 270° rotation. The OP seems to have it one way and needs it the other way. I have not yet had the requirement for a specific way. Thus, I unfortunately know no tool to help.

Comment: The issue appears only on printing. The PDF is created into a PS file using a toolchain including ghostscript. The resulting PS file is sent to the printer directly. The printer is in this case not recognizing, that the file should be rotated to fit on the page and prints the A4 landscape form as if it was in portrait and cuts the right third off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you want, but I think it might be that you want to change the viewing rotation, counter-rotating the content and page dimensions to compensate.

In which case, the [CPDF command line tools](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) can do this:

```
cpdf -upright in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

which will make the viewing rotation 0, rotating the contents and changing the page dimensions to compensate. You can then change the viewing rotation as you like with

```
cpdf -rotate <angle> in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

(absolute) or

```
cpdf -rotate-by <angle> in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

(relative) where `<angle>` is `0, 90, 180, 270, 360`.

If this doesn't suffice, you also have

```
cpdf -rotate-contents <angle> in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

where  is a number of degrees to rotate clockwise, and

```
cpdf -mediabox "minx miny width height" in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot tell, if what you proposed would have served the same purpose. I will post what I have done to resolve it, but I am willing to give you the kudos if this would have solved it as well: First, I have created new pages in Adobe Illustrator with orientation landscape without rotation. Then I copied the content of the original PDF into the landscape one. To fit on the page, the content had to be rotated. Then I loaded the broken PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro, replaced all pages with the newly created ones. Now all fields were still rotated. I used Javascript to repair that.

Comment: Ok, I tried cpdf with the approach you mentioned. "upright" seems to fix, what I have done with Illustrator below! I need to test this tomorrow, this seems to be the fastest way to get the PDF to the expected orientation. The fields were not fixed with this, my JavaScript was still required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FoxitReader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/). Is it free and it has a function HOME -> ROTATE VIEW, which does what you want.

Comment: As I said, rotating the PDF did not help. On rotation, it prints correctly, but the generated images are now in portrait. I would need to change only the orientation. But then, all the elements in the page  still keep their rotation and stand off in a 90° angle from the layout.

Answer (score 0):

First I fixed the PDF.

It seems, that cpdf -upright will also fix this. If you cannot use cpdf, because of commercial use, you can use a manual approach as shown with Adobe Illustrator.

cpdf did not correct the Acrofields orientation and not the annotations in the pdf. I had to recreate the annotations. The Acrofields can be fixed using JavaScript as shown below.

1. open the PDF in Adobe Illustrator
2. Repeat for each page 1..n of your document, the current page is "x" in the following steps:
3. Create a new document in A4, landscape mode, make sure the size is exactly 297x210 (WxH)!

   1. Open the PDF page x in Illustrator
   2. Copy all Elements of page x onto the new document using copy / paste functions
   3. Use Object/Transform/Rotate to rotate to the right angle, usually you need -90° or +90°
   4. Place the rotated objects on the page to match your expectations
   5. Save the document as "page-x.pdf"
   6. Close the PDF page x
   7. Repeat with next page until done...
4. Open Acrobat X to merge the single page-....pdf into one large PDF. Check the online documentation if you are unsure about this. Don't mess the order of pages!
5. Open the broken PDF
6. Save with a new name
7. Open the pages tool, choose "replace pages" function.
8. Select the merged PDF as page source and replace all pages in the broken PDF with the fixed pages from the merged PDF.
9. You should see the fields, standing in a 90° angle from the position where they are supposed to be

Then I fixed the Acrofields using the PDF JavaScript in Acrobat Pro.

1. Open the Javascript console.
2. Enter the following script:

   ```
   var box = getPageBox();
   var  w = box[2] - box[0];
   var  h = box[1] - box[3]; 
   // left,top         right,bottom
   // bottom, h-left     top, h-right
   for(i=0; i<numFields; i++) {
       var f = getField(getNthFieldName(i));
       var orig = f.rect;
       f.rect = [orig[3], h-orig[0], orig[1], h-orig[2]];
       f.rotation = 0;
   }
   ```

   To execute, highlight the script and press the ENTER Key, NOT RETURN. The ENTER Key is the  enter-key on the keypad. This will execute the highlighted JavaScript. The formfields will be rotated by +90° and should be placed almost correct, but at least near the position, where they are supposed to be.
3. Go through all pages, select all fields on the page, and move all fields together to the right position.